# Doubles not calculated correctly

Tags: java, double

I do know i'm a beginner but this is strange for me.

```
double x=1/4
```

gives me 0.0 (exactly like that), but

```
double x=1/4.0 or x=1.0/4
```

gives me 0.25.

Is it normal???

Comment: All programmers need to understand the difference between integer and floating point division and how floating point numbers work.

Comment: Had no one who could tell me that :)

Comment: It's right there in the documentation for the Java / operator.  You need to read that stuff when you have problems.  You're a beginner - you have a lot to learn.

Comment: I've done some Fortran77, Pascal, MathLab...never had any problems of this type :/, so i was surprised.

Comment: FORTRAN does integer division that way, too.  ALL languages do: http://www.physics.usyd.edu.au/guides/f77errors.html

Comment: You may not see it in pascal as that distinguishes between '/' (division for floats) and 'div' (division for integers). So in Pascal x := 1/4; will convert 1 and 4 to floating point before the division and x will be 0.25. But x := 1 div 4; will result in 0.0 being assigned to x.

Comment: @duffymo You tell 'em! Make the OP feel bad so he never comes back. This site would be so much better without pesky questions...

Comment: Never used div :P for high precission engeneering calculations that i needed, so with my little programing experience that problem has never appeard. :)

Comment: How is providing correct information making anyone feel bad?    Please point out the ad hominem portion of my comments.

Comment: The first 16 years of my career were spent practicing mechanical engineering for a living.  I did finite element analysis for a living.  Believe me, high precision engineering calculations and scientific computing depends on knowing what integer division and floating point numbers are.

Comment: @duffymo is right...never too much of constructive criticism.
Thanks for reply, it's very helpfull.

Comment: Thank you for accepting it in the proper spirit, @DarekK.

Comment: @duffymo: I did exactly the same for living in last 10 years - never had to worry about precission of calculations...got software for that :P

Comment: I had to write a lot of subroutines to plug in and customize behavior for non-linear problems.  I always worried about it.

Comment: Hehe...i was just a simple structural engeneer :)
...so i rather have used your work.

Comment: Nothing simple about structures - great work.  I simulated manufacturing problems.  I enjoyed it very much.